# Having an issue with presentation of Hover states in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, user-experience

I am a UX guy. I make things look pretty and functional. My short coming in life seems to coding this evening and I apologize if I posted this wrong.

My issue is that when a user hovers over a picture `(background-image)#sthero-client-image` it is supposed to hide `#sthero-whitebar-copy` and display `#sthero-whitebar-heros-copy`. I am trying to do this via JavaScript, since I have three of these to do and it is not going well.

Here is the code: Again i have been playing with it so it's a little funky..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sthero-client-image").hover(function() {
    $("#sthero-whitebar-copy").css("display": "none");
    $("#sthero-whitebar-client-copy").css("display": "block");
  }, function() {
    // on mouseout, reset the background colour
    $("#sthero-whitebar-copy").css("display": "block");
    $("#sthero-whitebar-client-copy").css("display": "none");
  });
});
```

```css
.sthero-wrapper{
  height:420px;
  width:1220px;
}
.sthero-whitebar-hide{
  display: block;
}
.sthero-whitebar{
  width:1220px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left:1.5%;
  transform: translate(-.75%, -30%);
}
.sthero-whitebar-text-contianer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#sthero-whitebar-copy{
  font-family:'exo 2';
  font-size:42px;
  color:#000;
  display:block;
}
#sthero-whitebar-client-copy{
  font-family:'exo 2';
  font-size:42px;
  color:#000;
  display:none;
}
#sthero-whitebar-heros-copy{
  font-family:'exo 2';
  font-size:42px;
  color:#000;
  display:none;
}
#sthero-whitebar-family-copy{
  font-family:'exo 2';
  font-size:42px;
  color:#000;
  display:none;
}
#sthero-client-image{
  background-image: url(clients- 100.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:362px;
  float:left;
}
#sthero-client-image:hover{
  background-image: url(50client-1 00.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:362px;
  float:left;
}
.sthero-heros-image{
  background-image: url(heros- 100.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:450px;
  float:left;
}
.sthero-heros-image:hover{
  background-image: url(50hero- 100.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:450px;
  float:left;
}
.sthero-family-image{
  background-image: url(family- 100.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:408px;
  float:left;
}
.sthero-family-image:hover{
  background-image: url(50family- 100.jpg);
  background-repeat: no- repeat;
  height:420px;
  width:408px;
  float:left; 
}
.sthero-clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="sthero-wrapper">
  <div class ="sthero-whitebar"><div class ="sthero-whitebar-text-contianer">
  <div id="sthero-whitebar-copy">
    Who do you want to ship to ? 
  </div>
  <div id="sthero-whitebar-client-copy"> CLIENT'S</div>
  <div id="sthero-whitebar-heros-copy">HERO'S</div>
  <div id="sthero-whitebar-family-copy">FAMILY</div>
  </div></div>
  <div id="sthero-client-image"></div>
  <div class="sthero-heros-image"></div>
  <div class="sthero-family-image"></div>
  <div class ="sthero-clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML you are using too?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.css` jQuery code formatting is wrong, thus creating an error.

You are currently using this... `.css("display":"none");`

Instead you should be using a comma, not a colon... `.css("display","none");`

See working fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/3vsk1p09/

You can use `.hide()` and `.show()` as an alternative, this does the same as display none/block.

Comment: Technically you could leave the colon and change it to `.css({"display":"none"});` since the `.css()` function also supports objects.

Comment: Of course, either or I guess was trying to fix his error at the time but never heard back so not sure if it solved the issue anyway

Answer (score 0):

I assume this has been resolved but it can also be accomplished with straight CSS using the sibling combinator "~" or by attaching the hover event to the parent.

Hover on the parent (won't show the hand cursor unless you specify)

```
.sthero-wrapper:hover #sthero-whitebar-copy {
     display:none;
}
.sthero-wrapper:hover #sthero-whitebar-client-copy {
     display:block;
}
```

Sibling combinator route has the small requirement that the items you want to target must come AFTER the item you're referencing.

```
#sthero-client-image:hover ~ #sthero-whitebar-copy {
     display:none;
}
#sthero-client-image:hover ~ #sthero-whitebar-client-copy {
     display:block;
}
```

If you didn't want to write that a bunch of times you could add classes to each element denoting what you want and write the CSS once.